# Can Pandas perform row-wise min() and max() functions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my DataFrame I wish to clip the value of a particular column between 0 and 100. For instance, given the following:

```
  a  b
0 10 90
1 20 150
2 30 -30
```

I want to get:

```
  a  b   c
0 10 90  90
1 20 150 100
2 30 -30 0
```

I know that in Pandas certain arithmetic operations work across columns. For instance, I could double every number in column `b` like so:

```
>>>df["c"] = df["b"] * 2
>>>df
  a  b   c
0 10 90  180
1 20 150 300
2 30 -30 -60
```

However this doesn't work for built-in functions like `min` and `max`:

```
>>>df["c"] = min(100, max(0, df["b"]))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Is there some way to accomplish what I want efficiently?

Comment: try this: `df.max(axis=1)`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [`Series.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip.html):

```
df['c'] = df['b'].clip(0,100)
print (df)
    a    b    c
0  10   90   90
1  20  150  100
2  30  -30    0
```

Comment: yeah, this is it ! ;)

Comment: very elegant solution!

Answer (score 14):

You can use the Pandas min function across an axis. Then combine it with min/max

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.min.html

For example

```
df.max(axis=1)
```

But it looks like you want to clip the values instead of min/max.

Comment: Still giving a +1 because this answered my exact question, although you're right -- ultimately I wanted `.clip` and not `.max` for my particular use case

Answer (score 1):

A `numpy` view.  Not as elegant as `clip`.

**Option 1**

```
df.assign(c=np.minimum(np.maximum(df.b.values, 0), 100))

    a    b    c
0  10   90   90
1  20  150  100
2  30  -30    0
```

---

**Option 2**

```
b = df.b.values
df.assign(c=np.where(b > 100, 100, np.where(b < 0, 0, b)))

    a    b    c
0  10   90   90
1  20  150  100
2  30  -30    0
```

---

**Timing**
*Code Below*

```
res.div(res.min(1), 0)

            pir1  pir2       jez1
10     30.895514   1.0  75.210427
30     28.611177   1.0  49.913498
100    20.658307   1.0  50.823106
300    19.842134   1.0  39.162901
1000   14.078159   1.0  25.148937
3000    8.767133   1.0  15.066847
10000   4.377849   1.0   8.849138
30000   2.634263   1.0   4.653956
```

[image]

```
res = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000, 30000],
    columns=['pir1', 'pir2', 'jez1'],
    dtype=float
)

jez1 = lambda d: d.assign(c=df.b.clip(0, 1))
pir1 = lambda d: d.assign(c=np.minimum(np.maximum(d.b.values, 0), 100))
pir2 = lambda d: (lambda b: np.where(b > 100, 100, np.where(b < 0, 0, b)))(d.b.values)

for i in res.index:
    d = pd.concat([df] * i, ignore_index=True)
    for j in res.columns:
        stmt = '{}(d)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import d, {}'.format(j)
        res.at[i, j] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=10)

res.plot(loglog=True)
```